# how to write my results to external file in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read some particular columns from myu data into my output file, i succeed in this reading one cloumn at a time but i want to read some more columns of my interest at a time (i have list of column i want to extract in a separate tex file) because extract individual column and joining them to make one separate file will become hectic to me, here is the code i tried to extract single coulmn,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (DATA, "<file.txt") or die ("Unable to open file");
my $search_string = "IADC512444";

my $header = <DATA>;
my @header_titles = split /\t/, $header;
my $extract_col = 0;

for my $header_line (@header_titles) {
  last if $header_line =~ m/$search_string/;
  $extract_col++;
}

print "Extracting column $extract_col\n";

while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
  last unless $row =~ /\S/;
  chomp $row;
  my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
  print "$cells[$extract_col] ";
}
```

is there any possibility to extract all columns at a time instead of only IADC512444 i want from my textfile into outfile on to my harddisc? please help me in solving this problem,
Thanks

Comment: any examples of input and output?

Comment: You have one answer already, but just for interest sake, I see you are refering to cells, are you extracting the data from a xls of csv file?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print the contents to a file on disk then you should open a file in write mode and write to it. Also if you want more columns you can do that by accessing corresponding element in the array cells. In this example i am printing the column you are printing plus column 1 and 2

```
open(OUT_FILE,">path_to_out_file") || die "cant open file...";
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
  last unless $row =~ /\S/;
  chomp $row;
  my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
  #print "$cells[$extract_col] ";
print OUT_FILE "$cells[$extract_col],$cells[1],$cells[2]\n";
}
close(OUT_FILE)
```

I have tweaked the code little bit to suit your requirement.
In the variable req_hdr_string you should say the column names which you require separated by ,
So it will be splitted and stored in a hash.
Then from the header i get the position of the column and print only those

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (DATA, "<h11.txt") or die ("Unable to open file");
my $req_hdr_string = "abc,ghi,mno,";
my %req_hdrs       = ();
my %extract_col    = ();
foreach(split /,/, $req_hdr_string)
{
    print "req hdr is:$_\n";
    $req_hdrs{$_} = $_;
}

my $index  = 0;
my $header = <DATA>;
chomp $header;
foreach (split /\t/, $header) 
{
    print "input is:|$_|\n";
    if(exists $req_hdrs{$_})
    {
        print "\treq index is:$index\n";
        $extract_col{$index} = 1;
    }
    $index++;
}

open(OUT_FILE,">out_file") || die "cant open file...";
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) 
{
    last unless $row =~ /\S/;
    chomp $row;
    my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
    foreach $index (sort keys%extract_col)
    {
        print OUT_FILE "$cells[$index],";
    }
    print OUT_FILE "\n";
}
close(OUT_FILE);
close(DATA);
```

Comment: Dear Raghu, thank you very much for your help in solving my problem, but i facing problem, if i want to extract 1200th column from my source file i should write my $cells [1200] in my print out_file? is there any wany to print columns as it is on to my output file without mentioning $cells [number]? because its very difficult for me to count column number from my source file because it contains 42K columns. what i want is what ever the column name i given in my search string i should get that column printed onto my output file. please suggest me in this regards, Thanking you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much Raghu for your help and its working fine. i am so thank full to you and you saved my time lot :)